# XSLT - match decimal with string and get text

Tags: html, xml, xslt, match

I have problem with matching.

I wanted like below at the end.

%3,00 CCC 
%5,00 AAA

%3,00 CCC 
%2,00 BBB

I got a help for it and have written somethings but got an error below if more than 1 `invoiceline`.

> Fatal Error: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of substring-after() ("11_003_AAA", "21_003_AAA", ...) A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of substring-after() ("11_003_AAA", "21_003_AAA", ...)"

**XML**

```
    <invoiceLine>
        <ID>000011</ID>
        <Note>40.00 BT</Note>
        <Note>17_                       2005.00</Note>
        <Note>11_005_AAA</Note>
        <Note>11_002_BBB</Note>
        <Note>11_003_CCC</Note>
        <AllowanceCharge>
            <MultiplierFactorNumeric>0.03</MultiplierFactorNumeric>
            <Amount currencyID="USD">6.00</Amount>
        </AllowanceCharge>
        <AllowanceCharge>
            <MultiplierFactorNumeric>0.05</MultiplierFactorNumeric>
        </AllowanceCharge>
    </invoiceLine>
<invoiceLine>
        <ID>000021</ID>
        <Note>10.00 CS</Note>
        <Note>17_                       1005.00</Note>
        <Note>21_005_AAA</Note>
        <Note>21_002_BBB</Note>
        <Note>21_003_CCC</Note>
        <AllowanceCharge>
            <MultiplierFactorNumeric>0.03</MultiplierFactorNumeric>
        </AllowanceCharge>
        <AllowanceCharge>
            <MultiplierFactorNumeric>0.02</MultiplierFactorNumeric>
        </AllowanceCharge>
    </invoiceLine>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="2.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="note" match="./Note" use="substring-before(substring-after(., '_'), '_')" />

   <xsl:template match="/invoiceline">
     <xsl:for-each select="./AllowanceCharge/MultiplierFactorNumeric">
       <xsl:text> %</xsl:text>
         
       <xsl:value-of select="format-number(. * 100, '###.##0,00', 'european')"/>,
        
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(key('note', format-number(100 * ., '000')), '_'), '_')"/>
            
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your XML `invoiceLine` doesn't match your XSLT `match="/invoiceline"`, and it doesn't make sense to match `/invoiceLine` if there are multiple of those elements, then they won't be the root element. Anyhow, you are selecting multiple `Note` from the `key()`, so you either need to iterate over each one and then perform the substring function on each item, or figure out which one you really want to select from the sequence of items matched from the key lookup.

Comment: @MadsHansen Why did you remove the `xslt-1.0` tag??

Comment: @FatihAydin: You tagged your question with [xslt-1.0] yet your stylesheet has `version="2.0"`.   Which version of XSLT are using?

Comment: @MadsHansen I just tried to write the necessary elements, for not too long. I guess I forgot some of it. sorry to it.

Comment: @kjhughes for this exactly using 2.0, but I am generally writing code for 1.0. therefore I wanted to know for 1.0 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your input is not a well-formed XML document. You must have a single root element - for example:

**XML**

```
<invoiceLines>
    <invoiceLine>
        <ID>000011</ID>
        <Note>40.00 BT</Note>
        <Note>17_                       2005.00</Note>
        <Note>11_005_AAA</Note>
        <Note>11_002_BBB</Note>
        <Note>11_003_CCC</Note>
        <AllowanceCharge>
            <MultiplierFactorNumeric>0.03</MultiplierFactorNumeric>
            <Amount currencyID="USD">6.00</Amount>
        </AllowanceCharge>
        <AllowanceCharge>
            <MultiplierFactorNumeric>0.05</MultiplierFactorNumeric>
        </AllowanceCharge>
    </invoiceLine>
    <invoiceLine>
        <ID>000021</ID>
        <Note>10.00 CS</Note>
        <Note>17_                       1005.00</Note>
        <Note>21_005_AAA</Note>
        <Note>21_002_BBB</Note>
        <Note>21_003_CCC</Note>
        <AllowanceCharge>
            <MultiplierFactorNumeric>0.03</MultiplierFactorNumeric>
        </AllowanceCharge>
        <AllowanceCharge>
            <MultiplierFactorNumeric>0.02</MultiplierFactorNumeric>
        </AllowanceCharge>
    </invoiceLine>
</invoiceLines>
```

Now, if you want the *key* to work only within the current `invoiceLine`, you must restrict it in some way. If you are able to use XSLT 2.0, then you can do it this way:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:key name="note" match="Note" use="tokenize(., '_')[2]" />
<xsl:decimal-format name="european" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>
  
<xsl:template match="/invoiceLines">
    <xsl:for-each select="invoiceLine">
        <xsl:for-each select="AllowanceCharge">
            <xsl:variable name="factor" select="100 * MultiplierFactorNumeric" />
            <xsl:text> %</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($factor, '#.##0,00', 'european')"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(key('note', format-number($factor, '000'), ..), '_')[3]"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

**Result**

```
 %3,00 CCC
 %5,00 AAA

 %3,00 CCC
 %2,00 BBB
```

Comment: thank you @michael.hor257k. you know previous example was single root element and your answer also worked for it. but when multiple root elements got an error. so i thought I need to add 2 root elements to understandable it. thank you again. :)